# Image moving when resizing window

Tags: html, css, resize, positioning

I've tried, several times, to get an image on my site not to move when resizing the window - without luck.

I "simply" want this image to stay exactly at the same place, regardless of the window size.

It's the image "kranz" I want at the top, over the text "this week's heroes". As you can see, the text stays at the same spot.

If you have any suggestions or solutions, I would be happy to hear them!

jsfiddle.net/VDfN4

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with the current code and exactly what you're trying to accomplish, but from what I can see the problem might be because of the absolute positioning on #kranz img. Try using position:relative or wrapping the kranz div in another div that is position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use percentages for placement.

```
#kranz img {
 position:absolute;
left:42%;
margin-left:-50px;
margin-top:-13%;
width:275px;
}
```

That left: 42% is 42% of the container width (or window width), the margin-top is 13% of the container height (or window height).... so if the window resizes and the container resizes  the measurement values change. Use pixels or some other absolute measurement rather than relative measurements such as percentages.